# Is there a better way to write a commutative function in F#/OCaml?

Tags: f#, ocaml, commutativity

Is there a more elegant or better way to write a commutative function in F#/OCaml rather than listing all possible cases?

```
let commutative x y = 
    match x,y with
        a, _ -> val1
       |_, a -> val1
       |b, _ -> val2
       |_, b -> val2
       ...
       |_,z -> |valN
```

While I was writing the question I thought one could make the function recursive and swap the arguments if no match is found.

```
let rec commutative x y = 
    match x,y with
     a,_ -> val1
    |b,_ -> val2
     ...
    |nox,noy -> commutative noy nox
```

But if I adopt this approach I cannot have in the function a default case that matches with everything unless I add another argument whose value indicates if it's the second time the function is being called and return the default value instead of calling the function with the swapped args if that's the case.

Any other ideas?
Does the language offer a construct for expressing the fact a function I'm defining is commutative?

Comment: In ocaml you can have multiple cases in the match so long as they capture the same variables with the same types. Eg you can write `| a, _ | _, a -> val1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm answering for OCaml only as my F# is extremely rusty.)

There's no special help in OCaml for defining commutative functions.

If your parameter type has a reasonable ordering relation you can swap them if necessary to make x the larger (say). Almost all types can be compared in OCaml, so this should work very commonly. (Things that can't be compared: function types, cyclic values.)

I'm not sure this would help, but it might reduce the number of cases that you need to write out:

```
let commutative x y =
    match (max x y, min x y) with
    | A, _ -> value
    . . .
```

Comment: In F# you can write this but the exhaustiveness check in the match will not take account of the functions `max` and `min` so you will lose safety this way.

Comment: In your experience, is this something done in practice? Or do people just write all the cases?

Comment: I don't see this kind of code all that often, so I can only give my opinion. It's worth some amount of extra computation to make the code clearer. But when writing a library you often write more efficient code that's a little less clear because it can make a big difference when the call ends up in an inner loop. If writing my own code I might use the ordering technique; if writing a library I'd consider just writing out all the cases. OCaml is excellent at making sure you don't forget a case.